# Golang store any struct in other struct field

Tags: go, struct

I have this code:

```
type TestData struct {
    Key string
}

type TemporaryStoreItem struct {
    key string
    data interface{}
    aliveUntil time.Time
}

func (s *TemporaryStoreItem) SetData(src interface{}) {
    src = s.data
}

data := TestData{
    Key: "value",
}

item := TemporaryStoreItem{
    key:     "item1",
    data:    data,
    aliveUntil: time.Now(),
}
oldItem := TestData{}
item.SetData(&oldItem)
```

I need to save any data or pointer to data in 'data' field of TemporaryStoreItem, and i need to get data as TestData struct(or any else source struct), what i do wrong, and is it possible to implement this idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func (s *TemporaryStoreItem) Data()interface{} {
    return s.data
}
data := TestData{
    Key: "TestData",
}

item := TemporaryStoreItem{
    key:     "item1",
    data:    data,
    aliveUntil: time.Now(),
}
oldItem := item.Data()
fmt.Println(oldItem)
```

Comment: it already set when i create item, i need to set data which stored in s.data to src.

Comment: Okay I understood what you are trying to do

Comment: Please check the edited answer and https://play.golang.org/p/lXYg4eS38TT

Comment: I changed your code a bit and it works) Thanks for help) https://play.golang.org/p/9uAqmYj6MQL